# How can I set stdout to be fully buffered in C?

Tags: c

Currently the first thing I do before I print anything in my program is run `setbuf(stdout, _IOFBF);`

However `printf("hello\n");` will still flush the buffer.

This is bad, I want to control when it sends all its text (In the interest of creating a "smooth" animated gif experience with ascii text in the terminal).

How can I tell my program I would like `stdout` to be fully buffered?

Comment: You can buffer it yourself: build a 2D array which represents the entire new "frame" and output it all at once. If you can position the cursor to top left first, it will be quicker because the console does not have to scroll.

Comment: How can I position the cursor at the top left from the program?

Comment: I believe [**ncurses**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) is a popular library to use. In Windows, I use [`SetConsoleCursorPosition()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolecursorposition).

Comment: @jkalsdfjk: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `setbuf` this way: `setbuf(stdout, _IOFBF);`. The second argument is a pointer to an array of `BUFSIZ` bytes.

You should instead use `setvbuf()` with a potentially larger buffer size before you perform any output:

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOFBF, 4096);
```

You can pass an actual array instead of `NULL` but it is not necessary as `setvbuf` will allocate the buffer if you don't and might still do that if you do. You may want to check the return value to ensure the call succeeded. If for some unexpected reason this call fails on your system, the output would not be fully buffered.

Here is the C Standard definition:

> **7.21.5.6 The `setvbuf` function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
>     #include <stdio.h>
>     int setvbuf(FILE * restrict stream,
>                 char * restrict buf, int mode, size_t size);
> ```
>
> The `setvbuf` function may be used only after the stream pointed to by `stream` has been associated with an open file and before any other operation (other than an unsuccessful call to `setvbuf`) is performed on the stream. The argument `mode` determines how `stream` will be buffered, as follows: `_IOFBF` causes input/output to be fully buffered; `_IOLBF` causes input/output to be line buffered; `_IONBF` causes input/output to be unbuffered. If `buf` is not a null pointer, the array it points to may be used instead of a buffer allocated by the `setvbuf` function and the argument `size` specifies the size of the array; otherwise, `size` may determine the size of a buffer allocated by the `setvbuf` function. The contents of the array at any time are indeterminate.
>
> **Returns**
>
> The `setvbuf` function returns zero on success, or nonzero if an invalid value is given for `mode` or if the request cannot be honored.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `setvbuf` to set the buffer mode, size, and location:

```
buffer = malloc(1024);
setvbuf(stdout, buffer, _IOFBF, 1024);
```

You need to ensure your buffer is large enough that it will never flush due to capacity if you want total control over flushing.